# Regular Expression to match string which doesn't contain substring

Tags: regex

I have a comma separated list as shown below. The list is actually on one line, but I have split it up to demonstrate the syntax and that each single unit contains 5 elements. There is no comma at the end of the list

```
ro:2581,1309531682152,A,Place,Page,
me:2642,1310989368864,A,Place,Page,
uk:2556,1309267095061,A,Place,Page,
me:2642,1310989380238,D,Place,Page,
me:2642,1334659643627,D,Place,Page,
ro:3562,1378721526696,A,Place,Page,
uk:1319,1309337246675,D,Place,Page,
ro:2581,1379500694666,D,Place,Page,
uk:1319,1309337246675,A,Place,Page
```

What I am trying to do is remove any unit (full line) that does not begin with uk:. I.e., the results will be:

```
uk:2556,1309267095061,A,Place,Page,
uk:1319,1309337246675,D,Place,Page,
uk:1319,1309337246675,A,Place,Page
```

If the string was on separate lines as my example, I could do this relatively easy, but because it is all on one line, I cannot get it to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Just to get it clear,is your input looks like something like this?: **ro:2581,1309531682152,A,Place,Pageme:2642,1310989368864,A,Place,Page** (note: there is no comma between "page" and "me")

Comment: Why do you need regex solution and what tool/platform are you using for this?

Comment: Lot's of confusing negations in your description. 'Doesn't contain' and 'remove.. that does not begin with'. You just plainly want all "rows" that begin with uk right?

Comment: @nafas. There IS a comma between "page" and "me". My actual string is ro:2581,1309531682152,A,Place,Page,me:2642,1310989368864,A,Place,Page,uk:2556,1309267095061,A,Place,Page,me:2642,1310989380238,D,Place,Page,me:2642,1334659643627,D,Place,Page,ro:3562,1378721526696,A,Place,Page,uk:1319,1309337246675,D,Place,Page,ro:2581,1379500694666,D,Place,Page,uk:1319,1309337246675,A,Place,Page

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. But maybe you're looking for something like this: `\b(?!uk)[a-z]+:\d+,\d+,[a-z]+,[a-z]+,[a-z]+,`. [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/jS1sS8/2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Comment: Check this out http://regex101.com/r/vG6gW3/1

Comment: @hex494D49 OP said the string is all one line. It was split up in the question for readability.

Comment: @Joe: How is that a duplicate of this question? Only the title seems to be the same.

Comment: @Typhoon101 ok, then the answer by **Revan** should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
(uk:\d+,\d+,\w,\w+,\w+)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nA0gX1/1)

It looks for `uk:` and then it's pretty much comma-counting from there on.

**EDIT:**

Since OP has now clarified that what they're using can only **remove** strings:

```
,?[^u][^k]:\d+,\d+,\w,\w+,\w+
```

[Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/nA0gX1/3)

This looks for an optional comma followed by two letters that are not `u` and not `k` in that order, then a colon (`:`), and then the rest of the regex is the same.

Comment: It seems a big chunk of my original question has somehow been removed, which clearly has caused a bit of confusion.  @RevanProdigalKnight, this is the closest answer. What is missing from the question is, I am using a custom language of my CMS, which only allows me to "remove" matched strings. Therefore, I actually need to match anything that DOES NOT begin with uk:, so I can remove it from the original. This will leave the lines that DO begin with uk:. In short, I need the opposite of this demo. I could probably use ((ro|me):\d+,\d+,\w,\w+,\w+), but in real life, there will be other values.

Comment: @Typhoon101 I've added a regex that should handle only removing the cases that don't begin with `uk:`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple regex like this:

```
(\buk:.+?,Page)(?:,|$)
```

and grab matched group #1

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jS1sS8/4)

Comment: Hope you have seen the linked demo :)

Comment: Of course I did :) The second match should stop on `ro:2581...`

Comment: [See it working here](http://regex101.com/r/jS1sS8/4) That is because OP has typed `Page` which was in hex: `0x6150 0x80e2 0xe28c 0x8b80 0x6567 0x000a`